Use Sumproduct in excel to find a match result in a string
I have a table with data as below.
code "aaa" has a cost of $200 allocated to it and
code "bbb" has a cost of $500 allocated to it.



Code
Cost Allocation




aaa;bbb
200;500


ccc
600



On another sheet, I would like to lookup the cost based on the code.
For code ccc I can use Sumproduct to find the cost = 500. But for code aaa and bbb, which excel function can I use to find the cost?
Column A  |  Column B

Code         Cost

ccc          600

aaa          200

bbb          500

I tried Sumproduct to find cost for code ccc. But for code bbb and ccc, I could not find a way to achieve the same result.

Rather than trying to generate a complicated formula that looks up the value from a badly structured input table, consider tackling the badly structured input table. Why are there two values for code and allocation in the same table row?

Because data saved from a user input form. One row = 1 unique invoice number, but within that invoice, the total invoice amount breaks down into different expense code. So when I save that invoice, I can only do that. For example: invoice total $700 in which $200 for expense with code aaa and $500 for expense with code bbb.

If one invoice for just one expense code, that wouldn't be a problem at all. But in this case, could anyone advise is there a better way to structure the data?

I added an answer below to show you how to do that.

Here is one way of doing this, however it is really not recommended or suggested to create unwanted layouts, which may result in creating complicated formulas as already been mentioned in the above comments.
That said, if you already have the same, then could try using the following by creating a custom LAMBDA() function and use with XLOOKUP() function. It is also assumed that number of delimiters per row will be max of 2.*


=LET(
     _Fx, LAMBDA(α, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(";"&α,";",{1,2}),";"),2)),
     --XLOOKUP(D2:D4,_Fx(Data[Code]),_Fx(Data[Cost Allocation]),""))


Or, if there are multiple codes then use SUM() function rather:
=LET(
     _Fx, LAMBDA(α, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(";"&α,";",{1,2}),";"),2)),
     --SUM((D2=_Fx(Data[Code]))*_Fx(Data[Cost Allocation])))


Updated Formula:
If in case the number of delimiters are more than 2 then use the following formula:
=LET(
     _Fx, LAMBDA(α, TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(";"&α,";",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(α)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(α,";",))+1))),";"),2)),
     --SUM((D2=_Fx(Data[Code]))*_Fx(Data[Cost Allocation])))



So the max delimiters per row max of 2? In real case, it could be more than 2. Is there a way to fix this formula to work with vary delimiters in a row? thanks so much

@RyanNguyen see the updated formula!

@RyanNguyen you have tried and it returned NA. Can you show me, how ? Because the solution is based on the context of your OP and which should work if the delimiters are more than 2 as well!

it was just my pasting mistake. your updated code works like a champ! much appreciated! I was about to give up on excel formula, because i could not find away to overcome this without vba and trying to build custom vba function for it but it works great.

@RyanNguyen nothing is hard once you learn to know how to do it. Thanks!

could you please show me where I can learn to build Lamda function? This is new to me

Sure here Click

This code will convert your existing list into a regular 2-column list:
=DROP(REDUCE("",BYROW(FILTER(A:B,A:A<>""),LAMBDA(rw,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,rw))),LAMBDA(arr,val,VSTACK(arr,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(val,";","|"))))),1)

You can then feed that in to a VLOOKUP:
=VLOOKUP(D1, DROP(REDUCE("",BYROW(FILTER(A:B,A:A<>""),LAMBDA(rw,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,rw))),LAMBDA(arr,val,VSTACK(arr,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(val,";","|"))))),1), 2, FALSE)


How it works:  First, we use a ByRow to convert each Row of the initial table into a single value, with a Pipe delimiter:
BYROW(FILTER(A:B,A:A<>""),LAMBDA(rw,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,rw)))

So:



Code
Cost Allocation




aaa;bbb
200;500


ccc
600



Becomes:



Code|Cost Allocation




aaa;bbb|200;500


ccc|600



Then we use a REDUCE to take each of those values, turn it into an Array, and Stack the Arrays on top of each other:
REDUCE("",[LIST],LAMBDA(arr,val,VSTACK(arr,TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(val,";","|")))))

(N.B. the TRANSPOSE is required because the TEXTSPLIT function can handle Columns within Rows, but not Rows within Columns; we have to build the Array sideways, and then flip it)
So, for example Code|Cost Allocation becomes









Code
Cost Allocation



and aaa;bbb|200;500 becomes









aaa
200


bbb
500



Which (when all stacked together) gives a result of









Code
Cost Allocation


aaa
200


bbb
500


ccc
600



(Then the Drop(.., 1) just gets rid of the Blank Row at top, so that "Code" and "Cost Allocation" become the Column Headings again)

To solve the underlying issue of a data format that is not ideal for reporting, you can clean up the table with Power Query. This will be more robust and less obscure than a formula solution.
The green normalised table in the screenshot below was generated purely by clicking ribbon commands. No knowledge of special code required.

Steps to arrive at the result are as follows, using two queries:
First Query - helper table

load the blue table into the Power Query Editor
delete the cost allocation column
split the code column by delimiter ; (set the columns to split into to the highest count of values you will expect in one cell, so it can adjust to changing data sets)
select the invoice column and unpivot all other columns
add an index column
rename the Value column to Code and remove the Attribute column
save and load this query as a connection only

Second Query - normalised table

load the blue table into the Power Query Editor again
delete the code column
split the cost allocation column by delimiter ; (set the columns to split into to the same number you used above)
select the invoice column and unpivot all other columns
add an index column
rename the Value column to cost allocation and remove the Attribute column
merge the code query with the index column as the key in both tables
Expand the table to keep only the code column
remove unwanted columns and rename what needs renaming
save the query to the worksheet

Now you can enjoy using simple SumIfs() functions or pivot tables to analyse the data.
If you get a new batch of data, just copy/paste it into the blue table and refresh the Power Query.
